# CSV generated with write.table has one row in the middle with fewer columns than every other row

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I'm generating thousands of CSVs with R in parallel using a cluster. Most of the CSVs turn out fine. However, some of them suffer from a problem that is boggling in that I have no idea how to replicate.

The problem is probably best illustrated by the following CSV excerpt:

```
"id","z1","z2","t","t0","d","runtime"
1,39.0107766942301,37.6647641938649,1,0,0,14.817
1,48.7828967951132,27.8792166300373,2,1,0,14.817 
.
.
.
1000,52.5137565503309,31.3138744122258,34,33,0,14.817
1000,48.7163379096316,30.5135773682921,35,34,0,14.817
1000,48.7682481798877,30.4314581446581,36,35,0,14.817
.785747185412,28.2949871247436,19,18,0,16.1849999999999
841,61.5267561510041,21.9846948710836,20,19,0,16.1849999999999
841,50.8342061013446,29.4827369026791,21,20,0,16.1849999999999
.
.
.
```

The rows corresponding to the first 1000 `id`s are what should be in the file. After the last `id = 1000` file, starting with the the next row, which is missing the `id` variable, the data seem to be coming from a different data file altogether because for each file, the `runtime` variable should be constant.

There are probably problems in my code. It seems likely that there is some heretofore undiscovered data frame merging going on. However, my question isn't about my coding inadequacies. My question is about how I would even going about producing a written CSV using R that has one row in the middle with one fewer columns than all the other rows.

The function used to write the file is `write.table(data_to_write, file = "filepath.csv", row.names = F, col.names = T, sep = ",")`

*EDIT*

I figured it out. Bad partitioning of file names. Sorry to waste everyone's time, but glad I learned something about SNOW.

Comment: Wait, your question says you want to know how to write a csv with a messed up row.  Did you mean how to avoid writing it?  Or how to read it?  What is it you want to achieve?  I suspect what is happening is not a bad merge, but two threads writing different tables to the same file.

Comment: Are each of these parallel processes writing to different file names? There's not two out there that are accidentally writing to the same file, right? Because it kind of looks like it.

Comment: @farnsy: I just want to know how it happened.

I thought it might be two threads trying to write to the same file. That shouldn't happen because the set of possible file names should be partitioned across threads. Plus, I've run into problems where different threads try to write to the same file and they always seem to either A)throw an error (some sort of permission error) or B)wait their turn. I'm not showing any errors, and for B) the file gets fully overwritten.

I recognize that I might be woefully ignorant about how the system I'm using will handle two threads writing to the same file.

Comment: The only way to produce a file with unequal columns in R like that is with `append=FALSE` in the `write.table` call.

Comment: Wait, I misread your comment Senor.

Comment: How the program interacts with files depends on your parallelization method (snow?).  If you can provide more info and a code example on how you do it, we might be able to help better.  But I think everyone here agrees that your threads are probably trying to access the same file.  Could be a partitioning problem on your part or a more subtle problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed the same behavior with the `snow` package for parallel computing. These errors occur if two processes write to the same file. The shorter the calculation (relatively more time spend writing to file) the more likely it gets.

If you're running parallelization via some loop or function, place a call to `Sys.getpid()` in there and construct a filename using `paste()`.

This works for my applications. One file per worker, no problem.